# making a react/redux implementation pattern reusable

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I implemented load on demand logic in a react/redux application page by invoking a page container `mapDispatchToProps` method in the page component's `componentDidMount` method.

The load on demand logic consists of these lines in the page component and its container:

```
import { isEmpty, isNil } from 'lodash';
import {SimplActions} from 'simpl-react/lib/actions';

class LoadOnDemandPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {run, loadedRun, loadRunData} = this.props;
    loadRunData(run, loadedRun);
  }
 
  .....
  
}

LoadOnDemandPage.propTypes = {
  run: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  loadedRun: PropTypes.object,

  loadRunData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {

    ...

  return {
    run,
    loadedRun: state.simpl.loaded_run,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadRunData(run, loadedRun) {
      if (!isNil(run)) {
        if (isEmpty(loadedRun) || run.pk != loadedRun.pk) {
          // load run's world data
          const runId = run.id;
          const topic = `model:model.run.${runId}`;
          dispatch(SimplActions.getDataTree(topic));
          dispatch(SimplActions.setLoadedRun(runId));
        }
      }
    },
  };
};

const module = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoadOnDemandPage);

export default withRouter(module);
```

Now, I'd like to use the same mapDispatchToProps `loadRunData` method in other pages and other applications by moving it into an external library.

Can this logic be made reusable or must it be replicated in every page component that uses this pattern? FWIW I'm using react v16 and redux v3.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a currying function that takes `dispatch`, saving in some `utils` folder:

```
  // above import dependencies
  const loadRunDataBuilder = dispatch => (run, loadedRun) {
    if (!isNil(run)) {
      if (isEmpty(loadedRun) || run.pk != loadedRun.pk) {
        // load run's world data
        const runId = run.id;
        const topic = `model:model.run.${runId}`;
        dispatch(SimplActions.getDataTree(topic));
        dispatch(SimplActions.setLoadedRun(runId));
      }
    }
  },
```

now you could import that function at any component and call it passing dispatch

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadRunData: loadRunDataBuilder(dispatch)
   },
 };
```

Comment: After adding your loadRunDataBuilder function, invoking it as
`curriedLoadRunData: loadRunDataBuilder(dispatch)` in mapDispatchToProps using `curriedLoadRunData(run, loadedRun);` results in the page going into an infinite loading loop. Even if it didn't, this solution would likely confuse later developers.

Comment: After getting everything working, I realized the two actions could be combined into one. Doing that eliminated one of the arguments and provides fewer ways to make errors.